# apply hover to text and not whole div

Tags: html, css, hover

I have an easy question here.

I have an image and a text that need to be activated at the same time when hover. At the moment it's working but the text apply hover to all the row size and not just to the text size, so when the cursor is on blank space I would like to rest and not apply hover state.

```
<section id="portfolio">
            <div id="portfolio-content" class="separation">
                <a href="nacho-costa.html"><article class="col-left project responsive-col-1">
                    <div class="project-cover">
                        <img src="img/nacho-costa.jpg" class="over">
                        <img src="img/grid-black.jpg" class="under">
                    <div class="textdescription">
                    <h3 class="notranslate">Nacho Cosa></h3>
                    <h2 class="notranslate">Branding</h2>
                    <h4 class="date notranslate">01-2017</h4>

                </article></a>
```

the CSS

```
    .project:hover .project-cover > .over {display: none;}
    .project:hover .project-cover > .under {display: inherit;}
    .project:hover h2, .project:hover h3, .project:hover h3 > span, .project:hover h4, .index:hover h2, .index:hover h3, .index:hover h3 > span, .index:hover h4 {color: #0000fc;}
```

Comment: I advise that you use a snippet or a fiddle to better illustrate your question

Comment: In your code by the way, you have closing div tags missing.